# Can I claim homeowner tax benefits if the title isn't in my name yet?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, trusts

My mom died at the end of 2018. Her living trust named me as trustee and indicated her house was to go to me. I failed to transfer the title to my name last year, but I paid the mortgage all year. Can I still claim homeowner benefits on my income taxes, or do I forfeit that because the title isn't in my name. The house is in the trust and I am trustee.

Comment: Does/did the trust file tax returns?

Comment: hmmm, interesting question. I don't think so.